# Adjust HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a personal time keeper I am putting together for work. We are allotted 50 minutes a week, and I wanted to make a fancy way of keeping track of that time.

I have a method that works:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <style> 

    #example1 {
        background-color="#0CD6C7";
    }


    </style>



    <div id="example2">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Personal Timer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setTimes(info) {
      var sel = info.split('|');
      document.getElementById('time1').value = sel[0];
      document.getElementById('time2').value = sel[1];
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#0CD6C7">
    <div id="example1">

    <hr align="left" size="0.5" color="white" width="82%">
    <br>
    <font face="arial">

    <input id="time1" value="50:00" size="5"> 50 minutes of personal time per week <br>
    <input id="time2" value="ex: 2:36" onfocus="this.value=''" size="5"> Type in the length of your personal break<br>

    <button onclick="document.getElementById('time1').value = timeAddSub('time1','time2',false)">Enter</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    // From: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?273699-add-2-fields-containing-time-values-in-hh-mm-format&daysprune=30

    Number.prototype.padDigit = function() { return (this < 10) ? '0'+this : ''+this; }

    function timeAddSub(id1, id2, flag) {  // flag=true to add values and flag=false to subtract values
      var tt1 = document.getElementById(id1).value;  if (tt1 == '') { return ''; }
      var t1 = tt1.split(':');
      var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  if (tt2 == '') { return ''; }
      var t2 = tt2.split(':');
      tt1 = Number(t1[0])*60+Number(t1[1]);
      tt2 = Number(t2[0])*60+Number(t2[1]);
      var diff = 0;  if (flag) { diff = tt1 + tt2; } else { diff = tt1 - tt2; }
      t1[0] = Math.abs(Math.floor(parseInt(diff / 60))).padDigit();  // form hours
      t1[1] = Math.abs(diff % 60).padDigit();                        // form minutes
      var tt1 = '';  if (diff < 0) { tt1 = '-'; } 
      // check for negative value
    return  document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = tt1+t1.join(':');

    }
    </script>
    </font>
    </body>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Enter in the length of the break in the second input field and that time is subtracted from the total.

To make it look fancier, I want the total time to appear as only text, not as an input field.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style> 



</style>


<div id="example2">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Personal Timer</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function setTimes(info) {
    var sel = info.split('|');
    document.getElementById('time1').innerHTML = sel[0];
    document.getElementById('time2').value = sel[1];
  }
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#0CD6C7">

<div id="example1">

<hr align="left" size="0.5" color="white" width="82%">
<br>
<font size="60" face="verdana" color="white">

<p id="time1"><font size="80"><b>50:00</b></p>


<font size="3" face="verdana">
<input id="time2" value="ex: 2:36" onfocus="this.value=''" size="5"> Type in the length of your break<br>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('time1').value = timeAddSub('time1', 'time2', false)">Enter</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
  // From: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?273699-add-2-fields-containing-time-values-in-hh-mm-format&daysprune=30

  Number.prototype.padDigit = function() { 
    return (this < 10) ? '0'+this : ''+this; 
  }

  function timeAddSub(id1, id2, flag) {  // flag=true to add values and flag=false to subtract values
    var tt1 = document.getElementById(id1).value;  if (tt1 == '') { return ''; }
    var t1 = tt1.split(':');
    var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  if (tt2 == '') { return ''; }
    var t2 = tt2.split(':');
    tt1 = Number(t1[0])*60+Number(t1[1]);
    tt2 = Number(t2[0])*60+Number(t2[1]);
    var diff = 0;  if (flag) { diff = tt1 + tt2; } else { diff = tt1 - tt2; }
    t1[1] = Math.abs(diff % 60).padDigit();                        // form minutes
    t1[0] = Math.abs(Math.floor(parseInt(diff / 60))).padDigit();  // form hours
    var tt1 = '';  if (diff < 0) { tt1 = '-'; } 
    // check for negative value
    return  document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = tt1+t1.join(':');

  }
</script>
</font>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

I know I need to use innerHTML, but it's just not quite clicking. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the below line

```
var tt1 = document.getElementById(id1).value;
```

to

```
var p = document.getElementById(id1);  
var tt1 = p.textContent;
```

This is because, `value` function is applicable only to `input` tags. For the other plain text tags like `p, headings`, etc. `textContent` should be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

What wrong is since t1 is a `p` tag, it doesn't have value so `tt1.split(':');` will throw an exception. Use `innerText` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style> 



</style>


<div id="example2">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Personal Timer</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function setTimes(info) {
    var sel = info.split('|');
    document.getElementById('time1').innerHTML = sel[0];
    document.getElementById('time2').value = sel[1];
  }
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#0CD6C7">

<div id="example1">

<hr align="left" size="0.5" color="white" width="82%">
<br>
<font size="60" face="verdana" color="white">

<p id="time1"><font size="80"><b>50:00</b></p>


<font size="3" face="verdana">
<input id="time2" value="ex: 2:36" onfocus="this.value=''" size="5"> Type in the length of your break<br>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('time1').value = timeAddSub('time1', 'time2', false)">Enter</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
  // From: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?273699-add-2-fields-containing-time-values-in-hh-mm-format&daysprune=30

  Number.prototype.padDigit = function() { 
    return (this < 10) ? '0'+this : ''+this; 
  }

  function timeAddSub(id1, id2, flag) {  // flag=true to add values and flag=false to subtract values
    var tt1 = document.getElementById(id1).innerText;  
    if (tt1 == '') { return ''; }
    
    var t1 = tt1.split(':');
    var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  if (tt2 == '') { return ''; }
    var t2 = tt2.split(':');
    tt1 = Number(t1[0])*60+Number(t1[1]);
    tt2 = Number(t2[0])*60+Number(t2[1]);
    var diff = 0;  
    if (flag) { diff = tt1 + tt2; } else { diff = tt1 - tt2; }
    t1[1] = Math.abs(diff % 60).padDigit();                        // form minutes
    t1[0] = Math.abs(Math.floor(parseInt(diff / 60))).padDigit();  // form hours
    var tt1 = '';  if (diff < 0) { tt1 = '-'; } 
    // check for negative value
    return  document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = tt1+t1.join(':');

  }
</script>
</font>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```